# Scala return keyword in map input function

Tags: scala, return

I was told that in Scala the **return** keyword was optional, I can write it or not (as for ;), no matter for the compiler

Please have a look at the following code:

```
  case class Data(x:Int)

  def test(data: List[Data]): List[Data] = {
    val newdata: List[Data] = data
      .map(d => {
        val newdx = d.x * 2
        return Data(newdx)
      })
    return newdata
  }
```

It doesn't compile, because of the return statement.

Putting the same logic, also with return, in the main method, actually compile and works.

So, what is the semantic of return?

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use `return` in Scala. Just write it as `data.map(d => d.x * 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure, but reading the error I would assume the following:

In this case, the `return Data(newdx)` returns from the `test`-function. The functions returns a list, while the return-statement returns da `Data` object.

when you don't write `return`, each value is mapped like intended, the list is created and returned.

You can remove the `return` from `return newdata`, since this is the last statement, which then returns your list.

Answer (score 1):

> A return expression return e must occur inside the body of some enclosing named method or function. The innermost enclosing named method or function in a source program, f , must have an explicitly declared result type, and the type of e must conform to it. The return expression evaluates the expression e and returns its value as the result of f . The evaluation of any statements or expressions following the return expression is omitted.

Avoid using `return` in Scala. Using return is not functional programming (it voilates the principles of functional programming).

Your code can be re-written as

```
def test(data: List[Data]): List[Data] = data.map(elem => Data(elem.x * 2))
```

More information about return in lambda function is here [Use of return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754976/scala-return-statements-in-anonymous-functions)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

**AFAIK**  In Scala, if there is no return then the last expression will be the return value.

In your `map` by writing `return` explicitly will cause `error` and so by simply keeping the expression the value appends to `List` referencing the `.map`