# method my_udf has return statement; needs result type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I read it is not required in most scenarios to specify a return type for a udf, but in case you add a `return` statement, then it is necessary.

I have the following udf, which internally iterates a list, and I would like that in case of match the udf returns immediately. Based on other answers I found on here I tried the following two approaches to define the return type:

```
def removeSalutation = udf((name: String) => String {

    val salutationList = List("MRS", "MR", "MSTR", "MISS", "MS", "DR")

    for(salutation <- salutationList){
        if(name.endsWith(salutation)){
            return name.dropRight(salutation.length())
        }
    }
    return name
    
})
```

above script just returns an error

```
def removeSalutation = udf[String, String]((name: String) => {

    val salutationList = List("MRS", "MR", "MSTR", "MISS", "MS", "DR")

    for(salutation <- salutationList){
        if(name.endsWith(salutation)){
            return name.dropRight(salutation.length())
        }
    }
    return name
    
})
```

Above script keeps saying:

> error: method removeSalutation has return statement; needs result type

What is the correct approach to specify the return type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the function separately as below:

```
def _removeSalutation(name: String) : String = {
    val salutationList = List("MRS", "MR", "MSTR", "MISS", "MS", "DR")
    for(salutation <- salutationList){
        if(name.endsWith(salutation)){
            return name.dropRight(salutation.length())
        }
    }
    return name
}

val removeSalutation = udf(_removeSalutation _)
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works. I was trying to  do everything in one go, that is withouh the last line you added, but seems it is not possible

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754976/scala-return-statements-in-anonymous-functions). Return is not supposed to be used in a lambda function in scala.

Comment: I am aware, and loops neither, actually I start the question with that. But I am no following purely the functional programming pattern in this case

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre on a second look, I think UDFs may not be necessary... why not use `replace`...?

Comment: This method is gonna be invoked from a Spark Dataframe. To clean a name field and generate a new column without salutation. Feel free to write below a cleaner way to achieve this, but with the UDF I believe can work find

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre try this? `df.select(regexp_replace($"col_name", "MRS$|MR$|MSTR$|MISS$|MS$|DR$", ""))`

Comment: Seems good, just only concern, the saludation should be removed only if present at the very end of the string. like if the name is Dratot or anything like that, the DR should not be removed

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre that's what the dollar sign is doing - it indicates end of line in regex