# How return works in scala on specific example?

Tags: scala

let's consider:

```
def foo: Int = { 
  val sumR: List[Int] => Int = _.foldLeft(0)((n, m) => return n + m)
  sumR(List(1,2,3)) + sumR(List(4,5,6))
}

scala> foo
res4: Int = 1
```

Why first part of `sumR(List(1,2,3)) + sumR(List(4,5,6))` expression is treated better? After all, `return` should lead to returning from `sumR`. So, why the result is not equal to `1+4`?

Comment: `return` causes the function to stop at that point and returns 1 because it's the first iteration in the `foldLeft` operation. The second sumR is not computed.

Comment: Have a look https://users.scala-lang.org/t/dont-use-return-in-scala/3688/11

Comment: @mck is it about the fact that `return` is syntatically in `foo`? To my eye, `return` should return from `sumR` function. After all, we have two calls of `sumR` so there should be two returns as well.

Comment: Yes, `return` pertains to `foo`. A lambda function cannot have a `return`.

Comment: Why? Because of lambda is expression?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754976/scala-return-statements-in-anonymous-functions) .

Comment: Never ever use `return` in **Scala**, or is not needed and can cause bugs like this one: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` is related to the `foo` method rather than the `sumR` function, so `return` causes the `foo` method to stop at that point and returns 1 because it's the first iteration in the `foldLeft` operation. The second `sumR` is not computed.

If you want 5 as the result, you should define `sumR` as a method rather than an anonymous function, so that `return` causes the `sumR` method to stop, rather than the `foo` method to stop.

```
def foo: Int = { 
  def sumR(l: List[Int]): Int = l.foldLeft(0)((n, m) => return n + m)
  sumR(List(1,2,3)) + sumR(List(4,5,6))
}

foo
// Int = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, very good answer. Anyway, it looks like `lambda` function is semantically differant than `def` function

Comment: Just in case someone want more information about the difference between **function** and *method**; it is a FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-methods-and-functions