# how to declare an annonymous function in scala with multiple returns?

Tags: scala

I want to declare a constant value `MyValue` of type string using the result of an anonymous function. Right now I have something similar using a declared function `getValue`

```scala
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
val n = 23

def getValue(): String = {
  if (n == 1) return "One"
  if (n == 2) return "Two"
  return "Another value"
}

val MyValue = (getValue())

println(n)
println(MyValue)
```

How could I use an anonymous function instead? So it would look like this

```scala
val n = 23

val MyValue = (() => {
  if (n == 1) return "One"
  if (n == 2) return "Two"
  return "Another value"
})()

println(n)
println(MyValue)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
ScalaFiddle.scala:7: error: return outside method definition
    if (n == 1) return "One"
                ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:8: error: return outside method definition
    if (n == 2) return "Two"
                ^
ScalaFiddle.scala:9: error: return outside method definition
    return "Another value"
    ^
```

Comment: Don't use `return` in Scala. More details in [this blog post](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754976/scala-return-statements-in-anonymous-functions) might also help.

Comment: Why a lambda of no arguments that you want to call immediately? Why not just assign the whole `if` expression to your value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `return` and use `else` in the conditionals:

```
val MyValue = (
    () => {
        if (n==1) "One" 
        else if (n==2) "Two" 
        else "Another value"
    }
)()
```

Comment: This way it always returns `Another value`